# lodash - nested search through JSON

Tags: javascript, json, lodash

I have a nested JSON object which looks similar to this:

```
{
"data": {
    "periods": [
        {
            "number": 0,
            "halfs": [
                {
                    "half": 1,
                    "events": [
                        {
                            "event": "abc"
                            ....
                        },
                        {
                            "event": "xyz"
                            ...
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "half": 2,
                    "events": [
                        {
                            "event": "abc"
                            ....
                        },
                        {
                            "event": "xyz"
                            ...
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "number": 2,
            "halfs": [
                {
                    "half": 1,
                    "events": [
                        {
                            "event": "abc"
                            ....
                        },
                        {
                            "event": "xyz"
                            ...
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

}

I'm trying to use lodash to pull all the event objects (event: abc, event:xyz) objects. I know I can use .get(jsonObj, 'periods[1].halfs[0].events')); to get he data but this would require me to loop for N times. Is there a way I could get all of the objects with minimal looping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without _.flatMap:

```
var events = _.flatten(_.map(data.periods,function(p){
  return _.flatten(_.map(p.halfs,function(h){
    return h.events;
  }));
}));
```

For version 4.0.0 and above:

```
var events = _.flatMap(data.periods,function(p){
  return _.flatMap(p.halfs,function(h){ 
    return h.events;
  }));
}));
```

Comment: Starting with version 4.0.0 there is even a `_.flatMap` method: which would make the code even more simpler `var events = _.flatMap(data.periods,function(p){
  return _.flatMap(p.halfs,function(h){
    return h.events;
  }));
}));`

Comment: Thanks. Updated my answer based on your feedback.

Comment: and with ES6 could be shortened even more...`_.flatMap(data.periods, (p) => _.flatMap(p.halfs, (h) => h.events));`